# Seeking advice on passing function as parameter practice in browser js code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm really just wondering if this is the "right" way to do things, or if I'm missing something about modules; we don't use node, just browser, but maybe this is applicable to both. In page.js we have a function world() that we need a module (module.js) to be able to call. Exporting world() and importing it into module doesn't seem like the appropriate way to do things.

Why not? page.js is js that is only applicable to one html page (page.html); world() manipulates some specific UI elements on page.html, and isn't going to ever be reused anywhere else. Module.js does some ajax/server related work; this is done on a lot of other html pages, so of course we make it a module for easy reuse.

init() is the real entry point. Contrived example:

**page.js**

```
import mod from 'module.js'

function init() {
    hello(); // print 'hello' to console

    const options = {
        // pass the 'world' function to module.js
        functionParam: world, 

        // some other irrelevant options here
    };

    mod.print(options); // print 'world' to console
}

function hello() {
    console.log('hello');
}

function world() {
    console.log('world');
}
```

**module.js**

```
function print(options) {
    // should call the world function, we should see 'world' logged to console
    options.functionParam();
}

export default print;
```

Comment: Obvious questions I should have addressed: why not just call world() after hello(), inside of app.js? Reason for that is, module.js does say 10 steps of some processing. Once step 4 is finished, we want to notify the user. So module.js print() does steps 1 - 4, then calls world(), then continues to process steps 5 - 10

Comment: Yes, callbacks are a very common pattern (doesn't necessarily have anything to do with modules).

Comment: Thanks again @Bergi, I guess I'm mainly wondering about the module aspect. Since world() isn't exported I wondered why it would be available elsewhere/whether it really *should* be used elsewhere, etc.

Comment: Your other code doesn't use *`world`*. The `print` function doesn't import it, all it knows is an *arbitrary* `options.functionParam` function. This is good - the two modules are coupled loosely.

Comment: Yes makes sense now, thanks